# angularjs directive not upating with scope.$watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, coffeescript, pug

I am trying to focus an input based on a controller variable.  It initializes correctly printing value= false in the console and the variable is being udpated in the view by the controller but not in the directive.  Im using jade/coffeescript or Id create an example but this is pretty much it:

**Controller**

```
$scope.autofocus = false

$scope.somefunction = ->
  $scope.autofocus = true
```

**Directive.**

```
'use strict'

angular.module('myapp')
.directive 'gsautofocus', ($timeout, $parse) ->
    {
    link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
        model = $parse(attrs.gsautofocus)
        scope.$watch model, (value) ->
            console.log 'value=', value
            if value == true
                $timeout ->
                    element[0].focus()
                    return
            return
    }
```

**View**

```
input(type="text", gsautofocus="{{autofocus}}")
```

Comment: Where is the call to `somefunction`?

Comment: on submit of the form, that is getting called and setting the value of autofocus to true but the directive isn't console.logging the value change

Comment: Is a digest being triggered correctly? Can you show the submit code for the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$observe` on attribute like you you want to evaluate interpolated contain on each digest, `$watch` will not work on interpolated value.

### $observe

> `$observe(key, fn);`
>
> Observes an interpolated attribute.
>   The observer function will be invoked once during the next $digest
>   following compilation. The observer is then invoked whenever the
>   interpolated value changes.

**Code**

```
'use strict'

angular.module('myapp')
.directive 'gsautofocus', ($timeout) ->
    {
    link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
        attrs.$observe 'gsautofocus', (value) ->
            console.log 'value=', value
            if value == true
                $timeout ->
                    element[0].focus()
                    return
            return
    }
```